# How can I get a child div to float to the right?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/zg63R/

I am making a flag or sorts here.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Flag</title>

<style> 
#Flago { 
    width:  auto; 
    height: 100px; 
    border:thick; 
    border-color: black; 
    background-color: yellow; 
    padding: 5px; 
    display: inline-block; 
}

#l1 {
    height:  25px; 
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;     
}

#l2 {
    height:  25px; 
    width: 150px;
    background-color: green;    

}

#l3 {
    height:  25px; 
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;  

}

#l4 {
    height:  50px; 
    width: 50px;
    background-color: orange;   
    float: right; 
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id= "Flago"> 

    <div id="l1"></div>

    <div id="l2"></div>

    <div id="l3"></div>

    <div id="l4"></div>
 </div>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried all sorts of combinations of floats, but nothing seems to work. The orange row down the bottom needs to come up beside the green and  red rows. What is the error here?

Comment: Cna you share the fiddle to this ?

Comment: First consider to move everything inside the `<body>` tag

Comment: next to both off them, so its a square

Comment: @janakshah added fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `id="14"` div in 2nd order

```
<div id= "Flago"> 
    <div id="l1"> </div>
     <div id="l4"> </div>
    <div id="l2"> </div>
    <div id="l3"> </div>   
 </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Z3du/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
margin-top: -50px;
```

to #14

Answer (score 0):

You just need to simply float div thirteen left, that way its width plus that of div fourteen which has already been floated right fit perfectly side by side.

Worked for me on Firefox.